# Навигация и Модуль RewriteRule

Tags: php

Уважаемы специалисты!
Пытаюсь в который раз сделать навигацию на сайте, точнее в  категориях сайта.

Пытаюсь сформировать url ссылку такого формата
http://site.ru/catalog/?page=2/

в .htaccess включен модуль

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteBase /
```

Далее действую таким способом

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^([a-zA-Z0-9_-]+)/$ templ/lay/pages/catalog.php?lurl=$1
```

Осуществляю выборку с базы

```
$pagination = 3;
if (empty($_GET['page']) || ($_GET['page']) <= 0)
{
    $page = 1;
}
else
{
    $page = (int)$_GET['page'];
}
$query = "SELECT * FROM `articles` WHERE `category_id`='" .$value['category_id']. "'";
$rowquery = mysqli_query($dbc, $query);
$cont = mysqli_num_rows($rowquery);
$page_comm = ceil ($cont / $pagination);
if (!$page_comm) $page_comm = 1;
if ($page > $page_comm) $page = $page_comm;
$start = ($page - 1) * $pagination;[/code]
```

Далее передаю параметры выборки в функцию со статьями в которой прохожу в цикле и вывожу все статьи к данной категории, переменная `$start`, `$pagination` так же вставляю в запрос где определяю количество страниц которые будут выдоится на экран пользователю.

Далее, пишу функцию для навигации:

```
function pagination ($page, $page_comm, $value)
{
    /* ссылки навигации */
    $back = ''; // ссылка назад
    $forward = ''; // ссылка в перед
    $startpage = ''; // ссылка в начало
    $endpage = ''; // ссылка в конец
    $page2left = ''; // вторая страница слева
    $page1left = ''; // первая страница слева
    $page2right = ''; // вторая страница справа
    $page1right = ''; // первая страница справа

    // ссылка назад 
    if($page > 1)
    {
        $back = "<a class='nav_link' href='/" .$value. "/?page=" .($page -1). "/'>&larr; Предыдущая</a>";
    }

    // ссылка в перед 
    if($page < $page_comm)
    {
        $forward = "<a class='nav_link' href='/" .$value. "/?page=" .($page +1). "/'> Следующая &rarr;</a>";
    }

    // ссылка в начало 
    if($page > 3)
    {
        $startpage = "<a class='nav_link' href='/" .$value. "/?page=1'>в начало</a>";
    }

    // ссылка в конец 
    if($page < ($page_comm - 2))
    {
         $endpage = "<a class='nav_link' href='/" .$value. "/?page=" .($page_comm)."/'>Последняя</a>";
    }

    // вторая страница слева 
    if($page  - 2 > 0)
    {
        $page2left = "<a class='nav_link' href='/" .$value. "/?page=" .($page - 2). "/'>" .($page - 2). "</a>";
    }
    // первая страница слева
    if($page  - 1 > 0)
    {
         $page1left = "<a class='nav_link' href='/" .$value. "/?page=" .($page - 1). "/'>" .($page - 1). "</a>";
    }
    // вторая страница справа 
    if($page  + 2 <= $page_comm)
   {
       $page2right = "<a class='nav_link' href='/" .$value. "/?page=" .($page + 2). "/'>" .($page + 2). "</a>";
   }
   // первая страница справа 
   if($page  + 1 <= $page_comm){
       $page1right = "<a class='nav_link' href='/" .$value. "/?page=" .($page + 1). "/'>" .($page + 1). "</a>";
   }
   echo $startpage.$back.$page2left.$page1left.'<a class="nav_active">' .$page. '</a>'.$page1right.$page2right.$forward.$endpage;
}[/code]
```

вывожу результат работы функции в шаблоне с категориями

```
 echo '<center><div class="nav">';
    if ($page_comm > 1) pagination ($page, $page_comm, $value['animalurl']);
    echo '</div></center>';
```

Получаю прекрасно все стать и навигацию, но не задача-не могу переходить по страничкам, не получаю Get я так предполагаю. В чем загвоздка помогите люди знающие и имеющие дело когда нибудь с Модулем RewriteEngine!  
Спасибо всем, кто откликнется!

Answer (score 1):

http://site.ru/catalog/?page=2/ - что это за адрес такой?
Фактически вы в файл "catalog" передаете параметр "page" со значением "2/", очень странная конструкция.

Если "?page=2" представляется как имя папки, то как минимум необходимо вспомнить, что символ "?" в таком имени участвовать не может.

Например, необходимо из адреса "http://site.ru/catalog/2/" получить адрес "http://site.ru/catalog.php?page=2".
Предроложим, что .htaccess лежит в корне сайта.

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^catalog/([0-9]+)/?$ catalog.php?page=$1
```